# Retrieve inputs from custom DialogBox class

Tags: java, swing, interface, javafx-2, abstract

I have a Navigator class and a custom DialogBox class which is descended from GridPane.

```
    public DialogBox(final JDialog jdialog) {
    Label lblKeyName = new Label("Enter New Key");
    Label lblKeyType = new Label("Select Key Type");
    TextField txtKeyName = new TextField();
    ComboBox cboKeyType = new ComboBox();
    txtKeyName.getText();
    Button btnOk = new Button("OK");
    Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");

    btnOk.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            //TODO: Somehow return the values in the ComboBox and TextField
        }           
    });

    btnCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            jdialog.setVisible(false);
        }           
    });

    txtKeyName.prefWidth(300);
    cboKeyType.prefWidth(300);

    this.add(lblKeyName, 0, 0);
    this.add(lblKeyType, 0, 1);
    this.add(txtKeyName, 1, 0);
    this.add(cboKeyType, 1, 1);
    this.add(btnOk, 0, 2);
    this.add(btnCancel, 1, 2);
}
```

This is the constructor for my DialogBox.

```
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    testBox = new DialogBox(jdialog);
    fxPanel.setScene(new Scene(testBox));
    jdialog.add(fxPanel);
    jdialog.setVisible(true);
```

How can I retrieve the values in the TextField and ComboBox? I can slightly recall a long ago class where the professor mentioned a technique involving the calling class (Navigator in this case) implementing an Interface and then passing itself to the DialogBox class to retrieve values. Unfortunately I have not found anything and cannot remember how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dialog is modal, basically, once `btnOk` or `btnCancel` button is pressed you need to change some kind of state flag which you can interrogate to determine how the dialog was closed...

```
// This will also handle the use case where the user presses the "x" button...
private boolean wasCancelled = true;

//...

public boolean wasCancelled() {
    return wasCancelled;
}
```

In you action listeners, you need to set the state appropriately.

```
btnOk.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        wasCancelled = false;
        jdialog.setVisible(false);
    }           
});

btnCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        wasCancelled = true;
        jdialog.setVisible(false);
    }           
});
```

Now, once the dialog returns, you need to check this flag...

```
jdialog.add(fxPanel); 
jdialog.setVisible(true);
if (!jdialog.wasCancelled()) {
    //...
}
```

You then need to supply "getter" methods to allow a caller to extract the values from the dialog...

```
public String getKey() {
    return txtKeyName.getText();
}

public String getType() {
    return cboKeyType.getSelectionModel().getValue();
}
```

This will mean you will need to create these two fields as instance variables

Comment: Could you elaborate on where the "getter" methods are placed? I'm thinking the interface which my Navigator class will implement.

Comment: Without further details, at the moment, they need to be implemeted within your dialog...